# mongod runs but only outputs all output going to path and that's it

Tags: macos, mongodb

I am completely lost at the moment and would greatly appreciate your assistance.  I installed mongoDB through Homebrew and created a data/db directory on my hardrive at the root. Everything seemed fine so far.  I then proceeded to run mongod and I was met with the following :

```
all output going to: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
```

Here is the contents of the log file (the latest section of it) on my last run:

```
Wed Sep 26 18:46:19 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=7720 port=27017 dbpath=/usr/local/var/mongodb 64-bit host=Notionworks-MacBook-Pro.local
Wed Sep 26 18:46:19 [initandlisten] 
Wed Sep 26 18:46:19 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
Wed Sep 26 18:46:19 [initandlisten] db version v2.2.0, pdfile version 4.5
Wed Sep 26 18:46:19 [initandlisten] git version: f5e83eae9cfbec7fb7a071321928f00d1b0c5207
Wed Sep 26 18:46:19 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin bs-osx-106-x86-64-1.local 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386 i386 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Wed Sep 26 18:46:19 [initandlisten] options: { bind_ip: "127.0.0.1", config: "/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf", dbpath: "/usr/local/var/mongodb", logappend: "true", logpath: "/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log" }
Wed Sep 26 18:46:19 [initandlisten] journal dir=/usr/local/var/mongodb/journal
Wed Sep 26 18:46:19 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Wed Sep 26 18:46:19 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
Wed Sep 26 18:46:19 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

As far as I can tell, everything looks like it is running correctly (however I don't really know what I'm looking at).  The only thing that seems amis is the dbpath, which according to the documentation defaults to /data/db/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Sorry I forgot to mention that I did try to run mongo after running mongod.  Here's the code:

```
Notionworks-MacBook-Pro:locomotivecms Notionwork$ mongod
all output going to: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
mongo
db.test.save( { a: 1} )
db.test.find()
```

Does this look normal to you?  It doesn't return anything...

***UPDATE:***

Solved it!  I was being silly and trying to enter the command `mongo` in the same terminal window. I did not realize that you had to open a new window in order to run it.  There was no mention of having to open a new window in mongoDB's set-up tutorial, and I didn't put two and two together.  I was confounded, as I thought that mongoDB was just sitting there thinking...  It works great now!  All I have to figure out now is how to change mongoDB's default path permanently so that I wont have to change it every time with -- dbpath.  Right now it defaults to usr/local/var/mongodb.  I just have to find the config file and change that if possible...  Just found it in the log!  Yay!  I'll see if I can change it! Thanks again for your prompt replies!

Comment: This looks fine. You just need to connect with a client. In your explanation, did you leave out the problem perhaps?

Comment: Yeah sorry mate!  Check out my edit please!

Comment: I would suggest you to use Rockmongo (Others are also available) to connect and run queries on Mongodb

Comment: That'll be great for when I tie it in with future projects!  Right now I'm just trying to run commands in the shell through terminal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to start playing around with that instance just type

```
mongo
```

in a new terminal or run mongod with --fork

Answer (score 12):

The you need to change the limit of your files which is 266 right now.

** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000

Enter the following in the command-line to change it:
`ulimit -n 1000`

You might get maxproc error which changing it, you can find out more [on this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/15564/where-are-the-default-ulimits-specified-on-os-x-10-5)

Answer (score 3):

Type `mongo` in the new terminal.

Comment: This is the most concise and accurate answer about this issue